# What is connectClass in Knockout Sortable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm reading Knockout Sortable [documentation](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) and I'm having trouble understanding what connectClass does in Sortable. I understand that if it's used for Draggble, it you can only drag items into that specified class. However, I'm not following what connectClass will do in Sortable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connectClass` can be used when you have multiple sortables on a page and only certain ones can drop onto other ones. Let's say that you have sortables A, B, C, and D. Your app may only allow A and B to drop with each other and C and D to drop with each other. You can use `connectClass` to identify which sortables are connected.

Here is a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/brakyepb/

Comment: wow, thanks for the great answer! am I reading the documentation wrong or is this not explained in it well? and also why is there no actual class for that? ex <div class=''foo""></div>

Comment: It puts the class for you automatically on the container and configures the sortable to connect with others with that class. I'll have to try to improve the docs. Sorry that it caused confusion.